# Python (recursion problem):: when do i need to declare a list before using it in recursive function?

Tags: python

```
# GET MATRIX PATH (0,0-->3,3) dr-> destination row, dc-> destination column

def gmp(r,c,dr,dc):
    # base case  
    if r==dr and c==dc:
        return [""] 
   
    if c<dc:
        hpaths=gmp(r,c+1,dr,dc)
    if r<dr:
        vpaths=gmp(r+1,c,dr,dc)
    
    gmp_res=[]
    for path in hpaths:
        gmp_res.append("h"+path)
    for path in vpaths:
        gmp_res.append("v"+path)
    print(gmp_res)

gmp(0,0,3,3)
```

error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hpaths' referenced before assignment.`

I have found that if I declare hpaths and vpaths before using them in if statements then it shows no error and answer is correct.

whereas the program below to find possible stair path shows not without declaring path1, path2,path3 first.

```
# GET STAIRS PATH WORKING -- with options of jumping 1/2/3 steps at once.

def stairspath(n):
    if n==0:
        baseans=[]
        baseans.append("")
        return baseans
    elif n<0:
        baseans=[]
        return baseans
    
    paths1=stairspath(n-1)
    paths2=stairspath(n-2)
    paths3=stairspath(n-3)
    finalarr=[]
        
    for i in paths1:
        finalarr.append("1"+i)
    for i in paths2:
        finalarr.append("2"+i)
    for i in paths3:
        finalarr.append("3"+i)
        
    return finalarr
        
print(stairspath(4))
```

Comment: You have to ensure that `hpaths` is defined even if `c >= dc`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign *something* to hpaths and vpaths at the start of the function (or before that if statement).

If one of the if conditions is true (e.g. r is equal to dr but c and dc are different), then that variable never gets defined.

So, where it says

```
    if c<dc:
        hpaths=gmp(r,c+1,dr,dc)
    if r<dr:
        vpaths=gmp(r+1,c,dr,dc)
```

you need to have an 'in case', like

```
    if c<dc:
        hpaths=gmp(r,c+1,dr,dc)
    else:
        hpaths=something else
    if r<dr:
        vpaths=gmp(r+1,c,dr,dc)
    else:
        vpaths=something else
```

I'm not sure what to put here, because gmp() doesn't return anything, so you'll just have a list of `None`s. Change `print (gmp_res)` to `return gmp_res`.